# Proper Databse Engine for OS X App (Sales, Clients, Dictionaries etc)

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am looking for the proper database engine for my application. This app is financial kind of application with some sales information, base of clients and so on.

Is SQLite suitable for such kind of tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SQLite is suitable for such a task.